# How do I debug a custom step in cDevWorkflow?

Tags: c#

I was built my custom step and integrated it successfully in cDevWorkflow. But I was unable to debug it. What is the procedure to debug my custom step from workflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the technology page of CDEVWorkflow [link](http://www.cdevworkflow.com/cDevWorkflow/Technology.aspx)

--> CDevWorkflow: Runs as a Windows service.

If you want to debug your custom step running inside CDevWorkflow, you'll have to attach the debugger of Visual Studio to the windows service process.

[Attaching a debugger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/3s68z0b3.aspx)